PHPUnit function toArray() of mocked ArrayCollection returns null
I wanna create a MockObject of ArrayCollection if Doctrine with item(s) but $arrayCollection->toArray() returned null. My code as bellow:
$subEntity = $this->createMock(SubEntity::class);

$arrayCollection = $this->getMockBuilder(ArrayCollection::class)
   ->setConstructorArgs([
       [$subEntity]
])
->getMock();

$entity = $this->createMock(Entity::class);
$entity
    ->expects($this->once())
    ->method('getSubEntities')
    ->willReturn($arrayCollection);

$testingClass = new TestingClass();
$result = $testingClass->converts($entity);

$this->assertInstanceOf(OtherEntity::class, $result);

This is the converts() function:
class TestingClass {
    ...
    public function converts(iterable $object){
        return array_map(
            function ($item) { ... },
            $object->toArray()
        );
    }
    ....
}

I received error when running the test: TypeError: array_map(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type array, null given
Anybody has idea?

Why do you need to mock an array collection? That is simply a wrapper around a simple array - wouldn't it be easier to use this class directly?

I create a mock Entity which has a relationship OneToMany. I wanna mock that relationship returns a collection and pass the collection to a function of a converter. Inside that converter I call collection->toArray() for processing each item. So I need to implement $entity->method('relation')->willReturn($collection);. Can you recommend me other ways to do that?

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Why not set a "real" ArrayCollection to that entity instead of a mocked ArrayCollection, like $collection = new ArrayCollection([$entity]);?

I wish that but the CTO asked me to use MockObject. I implemented successfully for a relationship ManyToMany but for this one I couldnot. I have no idea why.

@nico-haase I updated the question. Hope you get more information about my issue.

Note that is related to your converts method implementation rather then original question: Your methods accepts iterable $object but then you are calling $object->toArray(). toArray() method is not available in all iterables. For example converts([]) will pass iterable type hint but ti will cause error during toArray call. I would suggest either limiting the param to Doctrine\Common\Collections\ReadableCollection that defines toArray method or use iterator_to_array() function instead.

By default in mock all methods of mocked object are replaced. If you don't define the behavior of method it will simply pretend the method was run and return null if return value is needed.
So there is no need to pass array you want to use to constructor unless you explicitly need to run ArrayCollection's constructor with that array. Instead you should set up toArray() method to return that array:
$arrayCollection->expects($this->any())
    ->method('toArray')
    ->willReturn([$subEntity]);

